# Remove array value from object using underscore

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have following object

```
object = {
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": "value2",
  "key3": [
     "arrayKey1": "arrayValue1",
     "arrayKey2": "arrayValue2",
     "arrayKey3": "arrayValue3"
   ]
};
```

When i am using _.omit(object, key3) is working fine. As it is removing the 'key3' correctly.
but what if i want to remove the arrayKey2 only and not the whole key3 ?

Comment: Your syntax is invalid. Is that an array or an object now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `object.key3` is *actually* an array:

```
object.key3 = _.reject(object.key3, function(val, idx){ return idx == 1 })
// Or using the new ES6 syntax:
object.key3 = _.reject(object.key3, (val, idx) => idx == 1)
```

If `object.key3` is an object:

```
object.key3 = _.omit(object.key3, 'arrayKey2')
```